# This is my code, and the :first-child is not working?

Tags: html, css

In this case `first-child` is not working? what should I do ? This is my code, and the `:first-child` is not working?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .circle:first-child {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 6s;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes example {
      0% {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
      }
      25% {
        left: 300px;
        border-radius: 0px;
      }
      50% {
        left: 300px;
        border-radius: 100px;
      }
      75% {
        left: 0px;
        border-radius: 100px;
      }
      100% {
        left: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is "_is not working_" supposed to mean? Your code steals your pocket money?

Comment: @RamondeVries it doesn't mean that. It means any first-child having the class .circle

Comment: inspect the code to notice the real first child if your body element

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `first-of-type` pseudo-class

> The **:first-of-type** [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

[MDN Web doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .circle:first-of-type{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 6s;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes example {
      0% {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
      }
      25% {
        left: 300px;
        border-radius: 0px;
      }
      50% {
        left: 300px;
        border-radius: 100px;
      }
      75% {
        left: 0px;
        border-radius: 100px;
      }
      100% {
        left: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</body>

</html>
```